# Render python list in pyqt Qwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

So i have a problem writing what i have as list in a python code into my Qwidget , what i want is : as i have a list of tweets , when i click on the button i want my code to write what i have in a list in the Qwidget i don't know what to use for the writing part , i thought of using QPlainTextEdit which i think is not right , can you give me an idea of what to use and how ?
here is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import gettweet
app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
get = QPushButton(widget)
get.setText("Get tweet")
get.move(64,32)
widget.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)
widget.setWindowTitle("Sentiments tweets")
QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(widget).setGeometry(300,0 , 500,600)
def window() :
    get.clicked.connect(button1_clicked)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()


def button1_clicked() :
    tweets = gettweet.get()
    for i in tweets :
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Comment: It depends on *how* you want to show them. You may consider QListWidget, or a standard QScrollArea filled with QLabels or custom widgets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i do not know if you want it like this but i made the application put the items that are in the list to the QPlainTextEdit.

you should edit and fix the code to make it like what you want because i edited it.

```py
from re import I
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()


def button1_clicked() :
    tweets = ["My love is mohammed almalki","i love mohammed almalki very much"]
    for i in tweets :
        MyQPlainTextEdit.setPlainText(i)

get = QPushButton(widget)
get.setText("Get tweet")
get.move(64,32)
widget.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)
widget.setWindowTitle("Sentiments tweets")

MyQPlainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(widget)
MyQPlainTextEdit.setGeometry(300,0 , 500,600)

def window() :
    get.clicked.connect(button1_clicked)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

and i will give you an idea

you can create a container and put in it a lot of QPlainTextEdit like you have of tweets for example you have 10 tweets and you want to show them you can make it like this:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class ForExample:

    Tweets = ["Oh i do not know if i will meet mohammed almalki or not i love him very much",
                "One of my favorite people is mohammed almalki",
                "OMG did you meet Mohammed?? oh my god i think that is your best day right?"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.Application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        self.Window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Window.resize(800,500)
        self.WindowLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.ScrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.ScrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.GroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.GroupBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.GroupBox.setLayout(self.GroupBoxLayout)

        self.ScrollArea.setWidget(self.GroupBox)

        def FunctionToDoTheWord():
            for i in range(len(self.Tweets)):
                self.GroupBoxLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.Tweets[i]))

        self.ButtonToShowTheTweets = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show Tweets")
        self.ButtonToShowTheTweets.clicked.connect(FunctionToDoTheWord)
        
        
        self.WindowLayout.addWidget(self.ScrollArea)
        self.WindowLayout.addWidget(self.ButtonToShowTheTweets)

        self.Window.setLayout(self.WindowLayout)
        self.Window.show()
        self.Application.exec()

ForExample()
```

try this and tell me.